# Is there an objective way to know what skills are common knowledge when helping a client with their IT problems?

Tags: user

I'm a programmer, but I often end up being asked to help people with (what I think) are trivial IT questions.  I don't want to be condescending ("do you know how to cut and paste?"), but also I tend to assume certain skills are common knowledge when, apparently, they aren't.

My question is: is there any OBJECTIVE way to gauge what skills are "common knowledge"?  Like a survey site where I could look up a skill (for example, "create a fillable PDF") and see a percentage of users who are likely to know how to do that?  Or some other means of reference?

Comment: Even if there were such a site or reference, that would give you only an average measure of a large number of people's knowledge. That's not what you need. You need to know and be sensitive to the knowledge of the particular user with whom you're dealing. No one else's knowledge is relevant.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning recommendations are off-topic because they quickly become outdated and attract opinion-based answers. The survey site recommendation is off-topic even though your question is not off-topic in my opinion. So I suggest that you edit out the "Like a survey site" part and instead ask for the question to be answered here directly, as it already has been.

Answer (score 0):

Knowledge, only some potential, which contributes to the solution of problems.

That statement and subsequently solving problems is important, for which many experts believe the reward. Sometimes, it's money).

Usually you are dealing with a magic square SWOT analysis. Where are the two axes of knowledge and solving problems that divide employees into 4 segments. 1. or may not have the necessary knowledge, but to solve the problem successfully. 2. Those without knowledge and does not solve the problem. 3. Those who know and decide. And 4 - those who know and do not decide).

Testing knowledge of simple solutions is usually directly harm the company.

Because does not reveal the categories 1,4 and kills morale workforce.

I would say more, corporate rules that determine what is the problem are one of the architectural ideas and a set of rules, the problem should be solved. Often these architectures provide narrow and is not the best approach. Or paradigm too monstrous or not correspond to the level of development of the organization.

When ingenious solutions are rejected.

Remember, flexibility and reasonable risk have the right to exist.

I for example would like to shoot rubber bullets at those who make uncomfortable decisions. Believe me, it is very effective).

Believe me, in the world created quite uncomfortable things. And their presence is understood only when something hurts).

For example, when I had the flu with complications and I have every muscle ached, I was invited to work at night in one amusing big company ... I was surprised to find that a very important thing a comfortable chair.

What i mean?

Moreover, that assessment - a very subjective thing. They vary in accordance with the external conditions and your ideas about the problem.

The main assessments and hypotheses - advantage. And it is desirable that you have had enough of hypotheses to choose the best.

Perhaps my reasoning will help you).

Good Luck!